# Where is the second star coin located in S2-3?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I'm trying to get all the star coins in Super Mario 3D Land, but I'm unable to find the **second** star coin in level 3 of Special World 2.

Where is the second star coin located in the level S2-3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short while after the level's checkpoint, you'll come across a water jet while riding a green platform. The star coin is just above that jet, you have to try and stop the platform above the jet and jump for the coin when the platform's raised.